# converting from json to classic asp

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp-classic

I have a prototype system that is working in js

I call an test api using

```js
var promise = $.ajax({
    url: "myjson.json",
    method: "post",
    data:data,
    dataType: 'json'
}); 

promise.done(function (result) {
    window[callbackFunction](result);
})
```

this then passes the result to the callback function

which would enable me to do something like

```js
var valid = result.data[0].valid;
var type = result.data[0].type;
```

we are now changing the application to call an asp page which maybe something like

```vb
<%

  dim result1, dim result2

  valid = "this is a basic test";

  type = "more data"

  dim array(2)

  array(0)= valid
  array(1)= type

  response.write(array)

%>
```

In asp array will not write anything.

What I want to do is passback in the same format as before something like

```js
{"valid":"this is a basic test", "type":"moredata"}
```

So that I can read in the result in my js application

can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: weird i didnt realize that happened

Comment: You can't `response.write` an entire array like that. You have to loop through the index(es) and write out each value. (Also, `Array` is a built-in function; you might want to give your array a different name.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic ASP doesn't have anything built-in to support returning JSON Serialized data. You'll have to rely on a third party solution for that. A quick Google search shows the following as an option:

[Classic ASP JSON Class](http://www.aspjson.com/)

Comment: can we not just return an array rather than making it json?

Comment: @Dan - Without having a serializer to format the data for you, the ASP runtime has no idea how to format the data you want to return.

Comment: Slightly pedantic note - you need a solution like this if you're using VBScript as your scripting language.  Classic ASP also supports JScript, (basically Microsoft's interpretation of JavaScript), which handles JSON natively.