# Parse a JSON object using ASPjson

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

In Classic ASP (VBScript) I can do a general request of POST using `request.form` or GET using `request.querystring` which would give me the entire string that was sent.

But, I now need to receive a **JSON object** from a client side location.
This is an example of what it might look like:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "Smith",
  "age"      : 25
}
```

How do I request this entire object (which I will then be parsing with [ASP.JSON](https://www.aspjson.com/))?

*PS: I know that I can probably convert the JSON object to a string on the client side, and then parse as text on the server side, but that feels like a work-around rather than a straight solution.*

Comment: Whenever you pass JSON to a server you must serialise it and use the `Content-Type` header to inform the server-side ASP that you are sending `application/json`. It can then be deserialised by the ASP page using a library or custom code. There is no automatic modal binding in Classic ASP, you are best looking at ASP.Net MVC if you want that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converting from json to classic asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239695/converting-from-json-to-classic-asp)

Comment: Thanks, but no. As stated, I am already using ASPjson - my issue is reading the object that was sent by ajax, into the ASPjson component, which can then access the keys and values.

Comment: You understand right when you are talking about `Request.Form` and `Request.QueryString` you are talking about objects from the ASP Object library not VBScript. VBScript is just one of the scripting languages that Classic ASP can use for server-side processing. You also know right that ASPjson is a script library for parsing JSON in Classic ASP. Your [latest edit rolling back my changes](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67381980/5) suggests you don’t understand that.

Comment: This statement I’m struggling with; "I now need to receive a JSON object from a client side location". It’s not clear to me what you mean? You can send a serialised object through to a server-side script but retrieving one client-side from a server-side script?? You need to expand on your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't use that AspJson, but this: https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON

Second, you're not receiving an object *per se*, but request that contains a "string version of the json object". In this case, probably bytes, thats why you're going to BinaryRead and convert it into a body first.

You then will be able to parse the body with any parser you want.

Now let's try to give you an example code:

```
<%Response.LCID = 1033%>
<!--#include file="__jsonObject.class.v3.8.1.asp" -->

Set UTF8Enc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding") ' .NET COMPONENT, required on the server app pool
Set JSON = new JSONobject

lngBytesCount = Request.TotalBytes
request_body = UTF8Enc.GetString(Request.BinaryRead(lngBytesCount))

Set request_json = JSON.parse(request_body)

first_name = request_json("firstName")
last_name = request_json("lastName")
age = request_json("age")
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply - this response was spit on - thank you! Can you explain why this json library is better to use?

Comment: @kneidels just because of experience.. I find it more reliable and easier to read the "under the hood"